# Unable to Upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 "No New Version Found"

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, 14.10

I tried normal GUI Method, but there was no update there.
So i ran the command :

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

and

> sudo do-release-upgrade

and i got an error :

```
  Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

I have also checked my GUI Settings.
Attaching a screenshot for your reference :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL7Qv.png

Answer (score 0):

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

Run the update-manager application from the Unity Dash or a command line

In Update Manager, click the Settings... button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.

Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.

Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version", and change it if otherwise.
Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.
In Update Manager, click the Check button to check for new updates.

If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.

A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.
Click Upgrade.

Follow the on-screen instructions.

SOURCE:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UtopicUpgrades

Comment: I have already done that, still i cannot update.
Check my OP

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade -d